# javascript object property type accepts only number

Tags: javascript, json, object, model-view-controller, types

I make an Ajax Post request, sending below Javascript object as Json parameter to an MVC action:

```
 var productName, exchangeName, productCode, stockCode;
 var categoryID, brandID, stockAmount, state, shippingWeight;

 var sendinfo = 
            {
                "pcb": {
                    "ProductViewModel": {
                        "ProductName": + $('#ProductViewModel_ProductName').val()
                        "ProductCode": + $('#ProductViewModel_ProductCode').val(),
                        "StockCode": +$('#StockViewModel_StockCode').val(),
                        "StockAmount": +$('#StockViewModel_StockAmount').val(),
                        "ShippingWeight": +$('#ProductViewModel_ShippingWeight').val(),
                        "State": +state
                    },
                    "CategoryViewModel": { "Kategori": +categoryID },
                    "BrandViewModel": { "BrandName": +brandID },
                    "ExchangeViewModel": { "ExchangeName": +exchangeName }
                }
            };
```

My problem is about type of these properties. Some are meant to be inputs as string, but this object only accepts numbers (i see when i hover on pcb), and outputs null when I enter string other than number. Why is this happening?

I tryed to convert properties one by one as:

```
string($('#StockViewModel_StockCode').val())
```

and also tryed JSON.stringify() but did not work inside this object...

Comment: Convert required value with `parseInt()`.

Comment: Can you also paste your form html code ? seems like you are using the wrong input type.

Comment: @Fawaz: No, `val` **always** returns a string for all form controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Because the code explicitly tells it to, using a unary `+`:

```
"ProductName": + $('#ProductViewModel_ProductName').val()
// ------------^
```

and

```
"CategoryViewModel": { "Kategori": +categoryID }
// --------------------------------^
```

and so on.

When you apply a unary `+` to a string, it's coerced to a number. If it can't be recognized as a valid number, the result is `NaN`. (You've said you're seeing `null`, which suggests that at some point, you're serializing to JSON; `NaN` is converted to `null` when serializing as JSON, since JSON has no `NaN` value.)

If you want strings, remove the `+` from the code producing the property in question.

Comment: Thank you very much, it Works!